# Google Custom Search in the Header

Tags: wordpress, google-custom-search

I'm trying to implement Google Custom Search box on a responsive Wordpress site and would like to place it in the header. Google says the code must be placed in the `<body>` though.
How can I place the Google search bar in the header and make it work properly?

Comment: We dont know where you want to place the code. Maybe post the header.php code here. But it looks like you want to put it by the navigation? If so then your navigation elements should be found in the header.php file.

Comment: I would like it to go on the navigation bar. The problem is Google specifically says the code needs to go in the body tag. As you can see this site has managed to place it in the header http://www.stonetemple.com/

Comment: Because they used this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-custom-search/ But they also added it as a widget.. So if your theme allows you to add widgets to your header, then you can add it there in the widgets. Otherwise you will need to add a custom widget area.

Answer (score 0):

Create a widget area and then place it in the header.
Thanks msbodetti for that answer